# Callback url for webhooks with DRF

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I am to receive notifications from a remote API in my application through a callback url I provided.

If my callback url is `https://example.com/api/v1/sell/callback`

and the remote API sends notifications using a `GET`  to my app this way

`https://example.com/api/v1/sell/callback?invoice_id=BNSLE30AL&address=1PTPiwZ4&transaction_hash=94d37dc&value=1075&confirmations=1`

This is the request the remote API sends.
The problem is all their requests receive a 404, I was expecting that I can receive the data in their response with `request.query_params` but I obviously can't because the remote API can't reach this endpoint.

This is the endpoint I used for the callback

```
@csrf_exempt
@list_route(methods=['GET'], permission_classes=[AllowAny])
def callback(self, request):
    print(request.query_params)
    print(request.data)
    return Response(status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

How do I make my endpoint reachable to the external API because all I get is a 404 error.

Extra info:
I am using django viewsets
when I make a request to `https://example.com/api/callback` without any params, I am able to hit that endpoint.

UPDATE:
I have added the request sent by the remote server, now I am thinking I might have to use a custom url with regex for this...thoughts?

UPDATE 2:

views.py

```
class InvoiceModelViewSet(ModelViewSet):
    model = Invoice
    serializer_class = InvoiceModelSerializer

    @csrf_exempt
    @list_route(methods=['POST', 'GET'], permission_classes=[AllowAny])
    def callback(self, request):
        print(request.query_params)
        return Response(status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

urls.py

using viewsets router

`router.register(r'sell', InvoiceModelViewSet , base_name='sell')`

Comment: Are you able to see any log information to compare between you hitting the API vs the external service hitting the API? It sounds weird because if you are able to access it externally (say using postman) then any other service would be able to as well, so it sounds like there is something else going on that's not related to your view/route.

Comment: As @CoolestNerdIII suggested, you should check your logs to see what's the actual url the external api is hitting, most probably different than what you're hitting.

Possible cases I would check; protocol (you hitting https but api trying to http or vice versa), or external api may be trying to hit a slightly different path, like  https://example.com/api/callback/BNSLE3

Comment: I have updated the question thanks

Comment: please add the route definition...

Comment: I have updated the question with the route definition and view

Comment: You posted the route for sell, I am assuming you have a separate route for callback? Can you post that as well? And you would not need a regex for this because this is passed as query parameters, not the route id itself.

Comment: using  `viewsets` and `@list_route`, this route will translate to `/sell/method_name` hence `sell/callback`

Comment: The issue could also be related to your trailing slash settings, by default django should redirect requests without a trailing slash in path to the one with a trailing slash, but if you disabled that and the api is hitting a url without a trailing slash, that could be causing the problem.

Comment: I had that problem earlier and fixed the trailing slash issue